# MC68000 assembly multiplication

Tags: assembly, multiplication, signed, 68000

Say we have the following:

```
MOVE.L #$1234ABCD,D0
MOVE.L #$45670012,D1
MULS   D0,D1
```

What will be the value of D1?

- According to a MC68000 simulator, it will be **0xFFFA146A**.
- According to the book, the two lowest order words of each register will be multiplied and the result will be stored as a longword. Therefore, it will be 0xABCD * 0x0012 = **0x000C146A**.

I notice the 146A values are the same as in the simulator, but where does the FFFA come from? Is the simulator wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I know 0 about Motorola's code, but I think its something to do with the fact your using a signed multiplier? Try using an unsigned multiplier.

Comment: That, and the fact the 0xABCD is a negative number in 16-bit 2s complement

Comment: Thomas is correct. MULS is for signed multiplication. MULU is, perhaps unsurprisingly, the mnemonic for unsigned multiplication and will produce the expected result, $C146A.

Answer (score 2):

The other comments already correctly tell what's going on. Here's just a (hopefully) clear summary:

The unsigned multiplication:

```
MOVE.L #$1234ABCD,D0
MOVE.L #$45670012,D1
MULU   D0,D1
```

will calculate like the following

```
0xABCD x 0x0012 = 0x000C146A
```

Which is the contents of D1 afterwards.

Whereas in the signed multiplication:

```
MOVE.L #$1234ABCD,D0
MOVE.L #$45670012,D1
MULS   D0,D1
```

0xABCD is the 2's-complement representation of the value -0x5433

```
-0x5433 x 0x0012 = -0x0005EB96
```

and that number in 32-bit 2's-complement is 0xFFFA146A which is the result in D1.

In both cases the upper words of the factors don't matter.

Edit (thx. Sep Roland and Peter Cordes):
In fact loading the registers with long values was part of the original question, but just adds to confusion.
The cpu will multiply two word sized values, and so it makes sense to load words:

```
MOVE #$ABCD,D0
MOVE #$0012,D1
```

PS: You can easily check the 32bit complement of the result with any hex calculator:
0x100000000 - 0x0005EB96 = 0xFFFA146A

Comment: Considering that the 68k multiplication uses 16-bit operands, it is surprising to see D0 and D1 getting loaded from *longword* immediates. This is wasteful of codesize and of execution speed. And especially in the case of D1, that will anyway get overwritten by the full longword product, its longword preloading is incomprehensible.

Comment: @SepRoland: That silliness was in the question.  This answer is good, but could be even better if it pointed that out explicitly, with an example like `$12345678 * $00000001` giving `0x00005678`.  Or `$1234ABCD * $1` with signed multiply giving `0xffffabcd`, the sign-extension of the low 16.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is precisely why I posted this below the answer and not below the question. I was trying to motivate the answerer in adding something similar to their answer where they were already pointing out that "the upper words of the factors don't matter".